# In Skype4COM how do you format a chat message

Tags: c#, skype4com

Skype4COM still works (apparently) and I see that it is possible to format the mood message with rtf stylings but I've not figured out how to format a chat message.

To give a little context I have a simple bot for a community in that takes new chatbox messages from the website and posts them into a Skype group so the moderators can use a regular platform for moderating that chatbox.

A problem is formatting. Ideally I want it like:

**Username:** Says a message

However just sending a message with `*Username:* Sends a message` produces that exact text. (I.E: doesn't apply the same formatting it would if you posted that same message into the Skype chat as a user)

I know Skype4COM is considered defunct and as far as I am aware is supposed to be discontinued and no longer working however since it is still working I am hoping that there still might be a way to accomplish what I want to achieve.

Comment: Skype4Com doesn't work for me - a message sent through Skype4Com is shown up on the Skype client, but it doesn't deliver to the recipient. This is probably because the feature [has been deprecated](http://blogs.skype.com/2013/11/06/feature-evolution-and-support-for-the-skype-desktop-api/).

Comment: Though the feature has been depreciated I can assure you for me, even with the latest Skype it works fine. All 2000+ of these messages are from a bot: http://i.imgur.com/l5R6XPu.png

Comment: That's weird. As for me, when a message is sent to a contact through the API, the sent message shows up on the actual Skype client with status 'sending' - and it's never delivered.